# Как с помощью jquery скопировать значение placeholder из input и добавить его в label

Tags: html, jquery

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
.alpha {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.alpha input,
.alpha label {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.omega {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  color: #ff0000;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="alpha">
  <input placeholder="Имя">
  <label class="omega"></label>
</div>
<div class="alpha">
  <input placeholder="Адрес">
  <label class="omega"></label>
</div>
```

Необходимо скопировать значение placeholder из каждого отдельного input и добавить его в label.

Сразу прописать в label нет возможности.

Как это реализовать с помощью скрипта?

**Благодарю за ответ!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ, казалось бы на поверхности. взять инпуты, у которых есть атрибут `placeholder`, обойти их всех, найти соседние `label` и вписать им значение

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[placeholder]").each(function(){
     $(this).next("label").text( $(this).attr('placeholder') );
  });
})
```

```css
.alpha {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.alpha input,
.alpha label {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.omega {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  color: #ff0000;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alpha">
  <input placeholder="Имя">
  <label class="omega"></label>
</div>
<div class="alpha">
  <input placeholder="Адрес">
  <label class="omega"></label>
</div>
```

Если инпуты снабдить id, а лейблы атрибутом `for`, то можно не привязываться к структуре DOM. но это видимо не ваш случай

Comment: Большое спасибо за рабочее решение! То что нужно!

Comment: @Slava ткните галку к ответу тогда

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, а можно ли сделать следующее: У label есть атрибут `data-tip` в целом выглядит как `<label class="omega" data-tip=""></label>`  можно ли копировать значение `placeholder` не просто в `label` а добавлять к `data-tip=""`  чтобы получилось как пример `<label class="omega" data-tip="Адрес"></label>` ?

Comment: @Slava вместо `text(...)` используйте `.data('tip', ...)` либо `.attr('data-tip', ...)`.

Comment: и опять, то что нужно! Огромное спасибо за помощь!